# How can I generate skeletal points of unfilled space?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Given an array of points coordinates, I would like to generate `n` new coordinates that best "define" the *unfilled* space.

The first part of my approach involves using K-Means clustering to generate `k` points that reasonably represent all of the points. I then thought to use these points to generate the skeletal points for the unfilled space.

An example is shown below. The initial points are shown as small dots, the K-Means cluster centers are shown as large dots (`k = 5`), and my human estimate of where the skeletal points should be placed are shown by yellow squares, where `n = 4`.

[image: estimated skeletal points]

What would be the best approach for generating these skeletal points for the unfilled space? (It seems almost like I need an "inverse clustering" algorithm.) Feel free to provide a solution that does not use the K-Means clustering shown; that was just my attempt at simplifying the problem.

```
# Dataset used:
X = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0], [0.1, 0.0], [0.2, 0.0], [0.2, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.4, 0.1],
    [0.4, 0.2], [0.5, 0.2], [0.5, 0.3], [0.6, 0.3], [0.7, 0.3], [0.8, 0.3],
    [0.9, 0.3], [0.9, 0.4], [0.9, 0.5], [0.9, 0.5], [0.9, 0.6], [0.9, 0.7],
    [0.9, 0.7], [0.9, 0.8], [0.8, 0.8], [0.8, 0.9], [0.7, 0.9], [0.6, 0.9],
    [0.5, 0.9], [0.4, 0.9], [0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 0.8], [0.3, 0.7], [0.2, 0.7],
    [0.2, 0.6], [0.2, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4]
])
```

Comment: I think that until you know how to do this mathematically, it's not a programming question.  It's a math/statistics/data-science question. It's not at all clear to me how to get your yellow points from your data (I mean even conceptually).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one attempt at translating what you have asked for:

1) Fill the area in question with a grid of regularly spaced points.

2) Remove from this regular grid the points which are near your initial points.

3) Use k-means clustering to cluster the remaining grid points.

If you have P initial points and intend to create k clusters I would remove roughly P * 100 / (P + k) % of the grid points. There should be some clever way to get the accuracy of using a very fine grid without actually processing all the grid points one by one, e.g. by recursively splitting the space up into chunks, but a simple grid might allow you to test out this idea quickly and see what it looks like.